# How can I convert columns of a pandas DataFrame into a list of lists?

Tags: python, dataframe, pandas

I have a pandas DataFrame with multiple columns.

```
2u    2s    4r     4n     4m   7h   7v
0     1     1      0      0     0    1
0     1     0      1      0     0    1
1     0     0      1      0     1    0
1     0     0      0      1     1    0
1     0     1      0      0     1    0
0     1     1      0      0     0    1
```

What I want to do is to convert this [`pandas.DataFrame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html) into a list like following

```
X = [
     [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
     [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
     [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
     [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
     [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
     [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
     [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1]
    ]
```

2u    2s    4r     4n     4m   7h   7v   are column headings. It will change in different situations, so don't bother about it.

Comment: For anyone who stumbles upon this question in the future: If your data is similar to the one in the OP, a seemingly homogenous grid/array structure, a Pandas DataFrame may not be the right choice of data structure. A NumPy array is probably more appropriate, or even just a plain Python list.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas DataFrame to List of Lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28006793/pandas-dataframe-to-list-of-lists)

Answer (score 73, accepted):

It looks like a transposed matrix:

```
df.values.T.tolist()
```

---

```
[list(l) for l in zip(*df.values)]
```

```
[[0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
 [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
 [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
 [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
 [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1]]
```

Comment: This returns a list of a list. A ``list(df.values.flatten())`` does the job.

Comment: @pms By looking at the OPs desired output it indeed looks like they want to create a list of lists. But you could probably convert your comment to answer as it could get deleted by some silly flag. Also, I personally found your comment very useful as I was looking for the single list option. Finally, this could be probably modified to `list(df.values.T.flatten())` so the values will be kept by column.

Comment: @pms, very good. You can also get a list with `df.values.flatten().tolist()`  Note: Google takes you here whether you want a list of list or whether you want to avoid a list of list: I wanted to avoid a list of list and `.flatten()` was the way.

Answer (score 2):

To change Dataframe into list use tolist() function to convert 
Let use say i have Dataframe df

to change into list you can simply use tolist() function

```
df.values.tolist()
```

You can also change a particular column in to list by using

```
df['column name'].values.tolist()
```