# Pandas DataFrame to List of Lists

Tags: python, pandas

It's easy to turn a list of lists into a pandas dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3],[3,4,5]])
```

But how do I turn df back into a list of lists?

```
lol = df.what_to_do_now?
print lol
# [[1,2,3],[3,4,5]]
```

Comment: `pd.DataFrame.what_to_do_now = lambda self: self.values.tolist(); lol = df.what_to_do_now(); print(lol) # [[1,2,3],[3,4,5]] ` it works if you can believe it.

Answer (score 283, accepted):

You could access the underlying array and call its `tolist` method:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3],[3,4,5]])
>>> lol = df.values.tolist()
>>> lol
[[1L, 2L, 3L], [3L, 4L, 5L]]
```

Comment: Why are there `L`s appended in the output?

Comment: L mean long, as opposed to int.

Comment: From v0.24 onwards, [it would be better to use `df.to_numpy().tolist()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54324513/4909087).

Comment: NOTE, this does not preserve the column ordering.  so watch out for that

Comment: There is no reason why it would not preserve the column ordering.

Comment: @RussellLego It doesn't?

Comment: @AMC it does not no

Comment: @RussellLego That seems a bit odd, do you happen to know of an example which could demonstrate that?

Answer (score 27):

If the data has column and index labels that you want to preserve, there are a few options.

Example data:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3],[3,4,5]], \
       columns=('first', 'second', 'third'), \
       index=('alpha', 'beta')) 
>>> df
       first  second  third
alpha      1       2      3
beta       3       4      5
```

The `tolist()` method described in other answers is useful but yields only the core data - which may not be enough, depending on your needs.

```
>>> df.values.tolist()
[[1, 2, 3], [3, 4, 5]]
```

One approach is to convert the `DataFrame` to json using `df.to_json()` and then parse it again. This is cumbersome but does have some advantages, because the `to_json()` method has some useful options.

```
>>> df.to_json()
{
  "first":{"alpha":1,"beta":3},
  "second":{"alpha":2,"beta":4},"third":{"alpha":3,"beta":5}
}

>>> df.to_json(orient='split')
{
 "columns":["first","second","third"],
 "index":["alpha","beta"],
 "data":[[1,2,3],[3,4,5]]
}
```

Cumbersome but may be useful.

The good news is that it's pretty straightforward to build lists for the columns and rows:

```
>>> columns = [df.index.name] + [i for i in df.columns]
>>> rows = [[i for i in row] for row in df.itertuples()]
```

This yields:

```
>>> print(f"columns: {columns}\nrows: {rows}") 
columns: [None, 'first', 'second', 'third']
rows: [['alpha', 1, 2, 3], ['beta', 3, 4, 5]]
```

If the `None` as the name of the index is bothersome, rename it:

```
df = df.rename_axis('stage')
```

Then:

```
>>> columns = [df.index.name] + [i for i in df.columns]
>>> print(f"columns: {columns}\nrows: {rows}") 

columns: ['stage', 'first', 'second', 'third']
rows: [['alpha', 1, 2, 3], ['beta', 3, 4, 5]]
```

Comment: If you have a multilevel index, the index tuple will be the first element of the generated rows. You'll need a further step to split it.

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to use `DataFrame.itertuples()` or `DataFrame.to_records()` for all this?

Comment: @AMC Perhaps, I don't know, maybe? Rather than pontificate, why not add a proper treatment of that thought in your own answer?

Comment: @AndrewE Eh, it's still worth discussing and improving upon existing answers.

Answer (score 10):

I wanted to preserve the index, so I adapted the original answer to this solution:

```
list_df = df.reset_index().values.tolist()
```

Now you can paste it somewhere else (e.g. to paste into a Stack Overflow question) and latter recreate it:

```
pd.Dataframe(list_df, columns=['name1', ...])
pd.set_index(['name1'], inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 7):

I don't know if it will fit your needs, but you can also do:

```
>>> lol = df.values
>>> lol
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [3, 4, 5]])
```

This is just a numpy array from the ndarray module, which lets you do all the usual numpy array things.

Comment: Plus 1. *In practice*, there's often no need to convert the NumPy array into a list of lists.

Answer (score 6):

I had this problem: how do I get the headers of the df to be in row 0 for writing them to row 1 in the excel (using xlsxwriter)? None of the proposed solutions worked, but they pointed me in the right direction. I just needed one line more of code

```
# get csv data
df = pd.read_csv(filename)

# combine column headers and list of lists of values
lol = [df.columns.tolist()] + df.values.tolist()
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something changed but this gave back a list of ndarrays which did what I needed.

```
list(df.values)
```

Answer (score 2):

Not quite relate to the issue but another flavor with same expectation

converting data frame series into list of lists to plot the chart using create_distplot in Plotly

```
    hist_data=[]
    hist_data.append(map_data['Population'].to_numpy().tolist())
```

Answer (score 1):

"df.values" returns a numpy array. This does not preserve the data types. An integer might be converted to a float.

df.iterrows() returns a series which also does not guarantee to preserve the data types. See: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html

The code below converts to a list of list and preserves the data types:

```
rows = [list(row) for row in df.itertuples()]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to convert a `Pandas DataFrame` to a table (list of lists) and include the header column this should work:

```
import pandas as pd
def dfToTable(df:pd.DataFrame) -> list:
    return [list(df.columns)] + df.values.tolist()
```

Usage (in REPL):

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(
             [["r1c1","r1c2","r1c3"],["r2c1","r2c2","r3c3"]]
             , columns=["c1", "c2", "c3"])
>>> df
     c1    c2    c3
0  r1c1  r1c2  r1c3
1  r2c1  r2c2  r3c3
>>> dfToTable(df)
[['c1', 'c2', 'c3'], ['r1c1', 'r1c2', 'r1c3'], ['r2c1', 'r2c2', 'r3c3']]
```

Answer (score 1):

1. The solutions presented so far suffer from a "reinventing the wheel" approach. Quoting @AMC:

> If you're new to the library, consider double-checking whether the functionality you need is already offered by those Pandas objects.

2. If you convert a dataframe to a list of lists you will lose information - namely the index and columns names.

My solution: use [to_dict()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html)

```
dict_of_lists = df.to_dict(orient='split')
```

This will give you a dictionary with three lists: `index`, `columns`, `data`. If you decide you really don't need the columns and index names, you get the data with

```py
dict_of_lists['data']
```

Comment: The solution presented above is still "lossy". You will lose the name of the index and columns (`df.index.name` and `df.columns.name`)

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** I have seen many cases on Stack Overflow where converting a Pandas Series or DataFrame to a NumPy array or plain Python lists is entirely unecessary. If you're new to the library, consider double-checking whether the functionality you need is already offered by those Pandas objects.

To quote a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28006793/pandas-dataframe-to-list-of-lists/28006809#comment94894267_28007000) by @jpp:

> *In practice*, there's often no need to convert the NumPy array into a list of lists.

---

If a Pandas DataFrame/Series won't work, you can use the built-in [`DataFrame.to_numpy`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_numpy.html) and [`Series.to_numpy`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_numpy.html) methods.

Comment: This answer represents little more than your own beliefs. And quite frankly, it's a little embarrassing. There are perfectly valid reasons to convert a dataframe to a list/array, an advanced user would certainly know.

Comment: @NicolasGervais It might be a bit too much, yes, I'll edit it to generalize less. _There are perfectly valid reasons to convert a dataframe to a list/array_ Of course, my answer doesn't really say anything to the contrary. _an advanced user would certainly know._ I don't see the point of that jab. I wrote this answer after noticing that many people were converting series to ndarrays or lists, and ndarrays to lists, simply because they were unaware of what operations those objects support.

Comment: I'm referring to very blatant cases, like doing `for elem in some_series.values.tolist():` because they don't know that you can iterate over the elements of a series. I'm not sure what's so awful about this answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is very simple:

```
import numpy as np

list_of_lists = np.array(df)
```

Comment: How is this different from using `DataFrame.values` or `DataFrame.to_numpy()` ? Never mind the fact that it creates a NumPy array, not a plain Python list.

Answer (score 0):

A function I wrote that allows including the **index column** or the **header row**:

```py
def df_to_list_of_lists(df, index=False, header=False):
    rows = []
    if header:
        rows.append(([df.index.name] if index else []) + [e for e in df.columns])
    for row in df.itertuples():
        rows.append([e for e in row] if index else [e for e in row][1:])
    return rows
```

Answer (score -1):

We can use the DataFrame.iterrows() function to iterate over each of the rows of the given Dataframe and construct a list out of the data of each row:

```
# Empty list 
row_list =[] 

# Iterate over each row 
for index, rows in df.iterrows(): 
    # Create list for the current row 
    my_list =[rows.Date, rows.Event, rows.Cost] 

    # append the list to the final list 
    row_list.append(my_list) 

# Print 
print(row_list)
```

We can successfully extract each row of the given data frame into a list

Comment: This is not a good idea, try to avoid using df.iterrows because it's anti-pattern and slow once the df gets large: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16476924/how-to-iterate-over-rows-in-a-dataframe-in-pandas