# How can I make a this list in python?

Tags: python, list, pandas, python-3.5

Here is the sample list given, I am using the Python 3, and want to create the same list from the given panda's DataFrame from two columns Latitude and Longitude, but I don't want to use the For Loop, want to do with the `Pandas`function.

```
coordinates = [
    [  42.3581    ,  -71.0636    ],
    [  42.82995815,  -74.78991444],
    [  43.17929819,  -78.56603306],
    [  43.40320216,  -82.37774519],
    [  43.49975489,  -86.20965845],
    [  43.46811941,  -90.04569087],
    [  43.30857071,  -93.86961818],
    [  43.02248456,  -97.66563267],
    [  42.61228259, -101.41886832],
    [  42.08133868, -105.11585198],
    [  41.4338549 , -108.74485069],
    [  40.67471747, -112.29609954],
    [  39.8093434 , -115.76190821],
    [  38.84352776, -119.13665678],
    [  37.7833    , -122.4167    ]]
```

but I want it without using the for loop, is it possible with any Panda's function? or python function.

I hope this is clear now, for those people who said its not clear question.

Comment: What's wrong with what you've posted? There are no loops there.

Comment: There is no `for` loop in your question. What have you tried?

Comment: wait I didn't make that list, I want to make it from panda's Dataframe with two columns "Lat" and "Lon" and I want the output as given there

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pandas DataFrame to List of Lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28006793/pandas-dataframe-to-list-of-lists)

Comment: @Ravi : are you ok with dict format?

Comment: since someone was so kind and stopped the post ...if you want to change multidim list in onedim list use this forloop. for item in coordinates:
 for nitem in item:
  print(nitem)
  list.append(nitem)

Comment: @DRPK i want to pass to the some other function where it will plot all these co-ordinates on the map, so i guess dict won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your minimal question, I'm assuming you have a DataFrame like this:

```
    Lat   Lon
0    x0    y0
1    x1    y1
2    x2    y2
3    x3    y3
```

And you want it in a list form like this:

```
[[x0, y0], [x1, y1], [x2, y2], [x3, y3]]
```

So you just do this:

```
coordinates = list(zip(df.Lat.tolist(), df.Lon.tolist()))
```

Comment: when I print this, i get this result "<zip object at 0x0000025B826CB588>" any idea

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice you were using Python 3. In Python 2 it creates a list, but in Python 3 it creates an iterator. I've updated the answer.

Comment: even this is creating the tuples inside the list, not the list of list, but it worked somehow.. thanks