# Get row values as list when column value equal something

Tags: python, pandas

I want to extract the entire row values as list from `df` when column equal something.

I tried

```py
df.loc['column'== x]
```

but it gives the column headers and not a list

Basically I want is to parse through each row in df and get the entire row as list when df['column']==x .The column I am parsing is the first column (company name). For company x I would like to get the list of the values in all columns (I don't want the company name and the column names to be in the list. I just want the values). ps:There are no duplicates in the company names

Comment: df.loc[：, 'column'== x] .tolist()

Comment: I think you need to clarify your question.

Comment: Basically I want is to parse through each row in df and get the entire row as list when df['column']==x .The column I am parsing is the first column (company name). For company x I would like to get the list of the values in all columns (I don't want the company name and the column names to be in the list. I just want the values). ps:There are no duplicates in the company names

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `.loc()` to get only the rows that you are interested in. Then turn your Dataframe into a list of lists. So you need tyo get the values and turn them into list with `tolist()` method in Series.

You probably want to use:

```py
df.loc[df['column']==x].values.tolist()
```

Have a look at [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28006793/pandas-dataframe-to-list-of-lists)

## Here is an example:

```py
In [1]:
import pandas as pd

ipl_data = {'Team': ['Riders', 'Riders', 'Devils', 'Devils', 'Kings',
   'kings', 'Kings', 'Kings', 'Riders', 'Royals', 'Royals', 'Riders'],
   'Rank': [1, 2, 2, 3, 3,4 ,1 ,1,2 , 4,1,2],
   'Year': [2014,2015,2014,2015,2014,2015,2016,2017,2016,2014,2015,2017],
   'Points':[876,789,863,673,741,812,756,788,694,701,804,690]}
df = pd.DataFrame(ipl_data)
df.loc[df['Team']=='Riders'].values.tolist()

Out [1]:
[['Riders', 1, 2014, 876],
 ['Riders', 2, 2015, 789],
 ['Riders', 2, 2016, 694],
 ['Riders', 2, 2017, 690]]
```

Comment: df.loc[df['column']==x, 'column'].tolist()

Comment: Basically I want is to parse through each row in df and get the entire row as list when df['column']==x .The column I am parsing is the first column (company name). For company x I would like to get the list of the values in all columns (I don't want the company name and the column names to be in the list. I just want the values). ps:There are no duplicates in the company names

Comment: Okay, answer just edited. I think this is what you want

Comment: Out [1]:
[[ 1, 2014, 876],
 [ 2, 2015, 789],
 [ 2, 2016, 694],
 [ 2, 2017, 690]]    How can I get this output? Thank you!

Comment: Your answer works best. But I don't want the first column (team name in your example)

Comment: okay, then add `.drop(columns=['Team'], axis=1, inplace=True)` right before `.values.tolist()`