# Convert single df column to list of lists

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

How can you convert a single df column to a list of lists? using the df below, how can you return `X` to a list of lists.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({                
    'X' : [1,2,3,4,5,2,3,4,5,6],
    'Y' : [11,12,13,14,15,11,12,13,14,15],
    })

l = df['X'].values.tolist()

[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Converting two columns is possible:

```
l = df.values.tolist()
[[1, 11], [2, 12], [3, 13], [4, 14], [5, 15], [2, 11], [3, 12], [4, 13], [5, 14], [6, 15]]
```

But I just want X.

```
[[1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6]]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pandas DataFrame to List of Lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28006793/pandas-dataframe-to-list-of-lists)

Comment: I checked that @NatheerAlabsi. I've referenced the differences in the question

Comment: Don’t use `.values`. For the sake of curiosity, why do you need to do this?

Comment: Also, could you tell me if the solution I posted works correctly? I don’t have access to a computer right now, so I want to be entirely certain.

Comment: yep this works. I need it for a later function. Specifically, to iterate more efficiently. Did you down vote everyones post?

Comment: @jonboy It seems like it, in the end. Do you want to know why, for any particular one? I am curious to know what kind of iteration requires singleton lists. Presumably it is more efficient that using Pandas?

Comment: Inefficiency for the down votes I assume? I need to animate in a later function.

Comment: @jonboy For the downvotes, you mean? Ooh, animation, I definitely did not expect that one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
 df['X'].apply(lambda x: [x]).tolist()
```

output:

```
[[1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6]]
```

Comment: I’m pretty sure you could just do `.map(list).tolist()`.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC

```
df.X.values[:,None].tolist()
Out[85]: [[1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Some of these solutions seem overcomplicated. I believe this should do the job.

```py
res_list = [[elem] for elem in df['X']]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want this output

```
[[1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6]]
```

when starting with the input: `[1,2,3,4,5,2,3,4,5,6]`

then this should work fine

```py
l = [[i] for i in df['X'].values.tolist()]
```

Comment: Why the `.values.tolist()`?