# How to Concat Dataframe Pandas and Convert it into Multidimensional List on Python

Tags: python, pandas

i have a dataset structure like this :

```
| id | age | name | income |
----------------------------
|  0 |  9  |  AA  | 300    |
|  1 |  6  |  ZZ  | 100    |
```

and how to extract `age` and `income` and then combining again and convert those data into multidimentional list like this :

```
[
  [9, 300], 
  [6, 100]
]
```

i've tried a `concate` from pandas documentation, but it goes wrong when i converted it into list. my code is :

```
dataframe = pd.read_csv('my.csv')
data = pd.concat([dataset['age'], dataset['income']], axis=1)
```

everything is fine if i type `print(data)`, the result is dataframe is already merged.
But if i type `print(list(data))` the result i received is only **header's name** appear.

maybe you guys know how to solve my problem, any help will be appreciated

thanks

Comment: ```df.filter(['age','income']).to_numpy()``` ?

Comment: @sammywemmy thanks for the answer & your reply sam, i've tried your suggestion and it works, but i found another simple way to solve my case. :D

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], and clarify what exactly your question is. Why do you want a list, and what kind of list?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas DataFrame to List of Lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28006793/pandas-dataframe-to-list-of-lists)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure to understand why using `merge`.

Assuming you have a dataframe like

```
#    id  age name  income
# 0   0    9   AA     300
# 1   1    6   ZZ     100
```

You can try [`values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.values.html) followed by [`numpy.ndarray.tolist`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tolist.html):

```
df[["age", "income"]].values.tolist()
# [[9, 300], [6, 100]]
print(type(df[["age", "income"]].values.tolist()))
# <class 'list' >
```

---

[`values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.values.html) return a numpy array:

```
print(type(df[["age", "income"]].values))
# <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
print(df[["age", "income"]].values)
# [[  9 300]
#  [  6 100]]
```

Comment: woah, idk there is very simple way to solve this, lol. Thank you very much Alex !

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28006793/pandas-dataframe-to-list-of-lists