# Why is the last element in a pandas dataframe being displayed as the first element during a nested for loop in python?

Tags: python, pandas, nested-lists

While iterating through a nested for loop, I attempted to obtain a list of lists. Each list consisted of the data within each row of a dataframe. The reasoning behind this is not relevant; the behavior that occurred is what I am trying to understand. The initial code was as follows:

```
values = []
insert = []
for row in range(df_new_obs.shape[0]):
    print('row: ', row)
    print(insert)
    values.append(insert)
    insert = []

    for col in range(df_new_obs.shape[1]):
        insert.append(df_new_obs.iloc[row][col])
```

This code was able to construct the "list of lists" but failed to include the last row of the dataframe. The results of the initial code began with an empty array, followed by the dataframe rows from the beginning:

```
row: 0
[]
row: 1
['0', '0.0', '0', '1', '6', '179', '30', '19', '1', '0', '0', '0.11', '0']
row: 2
['1', '0.0', '0', '0', '6', '361', '28', '27', '0', '1', '4', '0.81', '1']
etc ...
```

I read a few posts to gain some insight on how iteration occurs in python and decided to alter the code to obtain the last row from the data frame. I was successful with the following code but cannot figure out why the last row of the dataframe showed up as the first element within the list. Can anyone offer an explanation/ insight on why this last row was so elusive and why it occurred as the first element?

```
values = []
insert = []
for row in range(df_new_obs.shape[0] + 1):
    print('row number:', row)
    print(insert)
    values.append(insert)
    insert = []
    for col in range(df_new_obs.shape[1]):
        insert.append(df_new_obs.iloc[row - 1][col])
```

Output:

```
row number: 0
[]
row number: 1
['0', '0.0', '0', '0', '7', '179', '53', '25', '0', '1', '1', '0.1', '0']
row number: 2
['0', '0.0', '0', '1', '6', '179', '30', '19', '1', '0', '0', '0.11', '0']
row number: 3
['1', '0.0', '0', '0', '6', '361', '28', '27', '0', '1', '4', '0.81', '1']
etc...
```

Comment: You can do this, https://stackoverflow.com/a/28006809/4985099 in combination with enumerate to get row index.

Answer (score 0):

The order of insertion is wrong - you add the last iterations `insert`  to your `values` - then you build up the new `insert`.

After the last `insert` was filled it does never get added to your `values`:

> ```
> values = []
> insert = []
> for row in range(df_new_obs.shape[0]):
>     print('row: ', row)
>     print(insert)
>     values.append(insert)         # ADDS empty on 1st execution of loop
>     insert = []
>
>     for col in range(df_new_obs.shape[1]):
>         insert.append(df_new_obs.iloc[row][col]) # add data, insert is added next loops iteration
> ```

You would need to add the latest built `insert` after the loop to get the last data as well:

```
# place after    for row in range(df_new_obs.shape[0]):    loop
values.append(insert)
```

---

Probably better to avoid the confusion by using

```
values = []
insert = []
for row in range(df_new_obs.shape[0]):
    print('row: ', row)
    insert = []

    for col in range(df_new_obs.shape[1]):
        insert.append(df_new_obs.iloc[row][col]) # add data to insert

    values.append(insert)  # adds insert to values
```

... or to use better ways to "export" your data from your dataframe: [Pandas DataFrame to List of Lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28006793/pandas-dataframe-to-list-of-lists)