# How to make each row of a DataFrame an array?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

If this is my data frame how do I convert it to array for each row?

```
            3        4        5        6       97       98       99      100
0         1.0      2.0      3.0      4.0     95.0     96.0     97.0     98.0
1     50699.0  16302.0  50700.0  16294.0  50735.0  16334.0  50737.0  16335.0
2     57530.0  33436.0  57531.0  33438.0      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN
3     24014.0  24015.0  34630.0  24016.0      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN
4     44933.0   2611.0  44936.0   2612.0  44982.0   2631.0  44972.0   2633.0
1792  46712.0  35340.0  46713.0  35341.0  46759.0  35387.0  46760.0  35388.0
1793  61283.0  40276.0  61284.0  40277.0  61330.0  40323.0  61331.0  40324.0
1794      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0
1795      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0
1796  27156.0  48331.0  27157.0  48332.0      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN
```

For example, I want it to be `[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 95.0, 96.0, 97.0, 98.0]` for the first one.

Comment: post sample data and your trial code

Comment: You can try this <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28006793/pandas-dataframe-to-list-of-lists>

Answer (score 0):

You can loop the dataframe's rows and assign the NumPy arrays dynamically to the global symbol table `dict`.
To loop rows, you can loop the transposes dataframe's columns.

```
# sample frame
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1' : [np.nan, 1.0, 4.5, 1.3, np.nan, 6.7],
                   'col2' : [-0.4, 0.5, -2.3, np.nan, 1.2, 2.4]})

# transpose 
df = df.transpose()

# dynamical assignment -> global symbol table
for i in df.columns:
    globals()['v{}'.format(i+1)] = np.array(df[i])

v1
>array([ nan, -0.4])

v2
>array([1. , 0.5])
```

**EDIT**: Added `tranpose() to provide rows rather than columns as in the initial answer. Thanks, BeRT2me

Comment: OP wants row-wise, not column wise. Also, a better way to do what you're doing would be: `df.apply(np.array, result_type='reduce')`

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> out = df.apply(np.array, axis=1) # df.apply(list, axis=1)
>>> print(out.to_frame('arrays'))
                                                 arrays
0          [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 95.0, 96.0, 97.0, 98.0]
1     [50699.0, 16302.0, 50700.0, 16294.0, 50735.0, ...
2     [57530.0, 33436.0, 57531.0, 33438.0, nan, nan,...
3     [24014.0, 24015.0, 34630.0, 24016.0, nan, nan,...
4     [44933.0, 2611.0, 44936.0, 2612.0, 44982.0, 26...
1792  [46712.0, 35340.0, 46713.0, 35341.0, 46759.0, ...
1793  [61283.0, 40276.0, 61284.0, 40277.0, 61330.0, ...
1794           [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
1795           [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
1796  [27156.0, 48331.0, 27157.0, 48332.0, nan, nan,...
```

---

```
>>> print(df.to_numpy().tolist())
[[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 95.0, 96.0, 97.0, 98.0],
 [50699.0, 16302.0, 50700.0, 16294.0, 50735.0, 16334.0, 50737.0, 16335.0],
 [57530.0, 33436.0, 57531.0, 33438.0, nan, nan, nan, nan],
 [24014.0, 24015.0, 34630.0, 24016.0, nan, nan, nan, nan],
 [44933.0, 2611.0, 44936.0, 2612.0, 44982.0, 2631.0, 44972.0, 2633.0],
 [46712.0, 35340.0, 46713.0, 35341.0, 46759.0, 35387.0, 46760.0, 35388.0],
 [61283.0, 40276.0, 61284.0, 40277.0, 61330.0, 40323.0, 61331.0, 40324.0],
 [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
 [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
 [27156.0, 48331.0, 27157.0, 48332.0, nan, nan, nan, nan]]
```

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
>>> rows = [*df.to_numpy()]  # list of arrays
>>> rows[0]
array([ 1.,  2.,  3.,  4., 95., 96., 97., 98.])
```

or since you seem to be using the words [`list`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) and [`array`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.array.html) interchangeably,

```
>>> [*rows] = map(list, df.to_numpy())  # list of lists
>>> rows[0]
[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 95.0, 96.0, 97.0, 98.0]
```

?

Comment: `rows = df.to_numpy().tolist()` is definitely better/more performant than `[*rows] = map(list, df.to_numpy())`

Comment: @BeRT2me True. The OP seems not to be clear on what he wants though. `map(list|tuple|set, ...)`.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want? You can try this by 'df.values' or 'np.array(df)'.

```
data = [[1, 10, 100],
    [2, 20, 200],
    [3, None, None]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=[1, 2, 3])
print(df)
print('------')
print(df.values)
print('------')
print(df.values[0])
print('------')
print(np.array(df))
print('------')
print(np.array(df)[0])
```

Output:

```
   1     2      3
0  1  10.0  100.0
1  2  20.0  200.0
2  3   NaN    NaN
------
[[  1.  10. 100.]
[  2.  20. 200.]
[  3.  nan  nan]]
------
[  1.  10. 100.]
------
[[  1.  10. 100.]
[  2.  20. 200.]
[  3.  nan  nan]]
------
[  1.  10. 100.]
```