# Create a dataframe based on a date range with other columns

Tags: python-3.x

Consider the following:
`start_date = input('Enter starting date in Month-Year format :')`
`end_date = input('Enter ending date in Month-Year format :')`
course = 'English'

if the user enter 01-2022 and 05-2022, the list of input will be the following:
['01-2022','05-2022','English']
I want to have a dataframe that looks like this:

| ID | Date | Course |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Jan-2022 | English |
| 2 | Feb-2022 | English |
| 3 | Mar-2022 | English |
| 4 | Apr-2022 | English |
| 5 | May-2022 | English |

If a new user provides new input such as ['01-2022','01-2022','Math']

I want to append this to the previous dataframe and have

| ID | Date | Course |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Jan-2022 | English |
| 2 | Feb-2022 | English |
| 3 | Mar-2022 | English |
| 4 | Apr-2022 | English |
| 5 | May-2022 | English |
| 6 | Jan-2022 | Math |

First, I tried generating a list of dates based on this date range with:

`month_list = pd.date_range('2014-10-10','2016-01-07', freq='MS').strftime("%b-%Y").tolist()`

the result was:

['Nov-2014',
'Dec-2014',
---
'Dec-2015',
'Jan-2016']

then wanted to convert this to a list of lists and append the course name before creating the dataframe from the new list.

Any help?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28006793/pandas-dataframe-to-list-of-lists could at least answer to create a list from lists in python with pandas.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a table .

```
ID  Date    Course
1   Jan-2022    English
2   Feb-2022    English
3   Mar-2022    English
4   Apr-2022    English
5   May-2022    English
6   Jan-2022    Math
```

you want to append new values at the end of the table then you can create a table for the new values with same column names and then concatenate the two tables. For example if you have a `month_list = ['Nov-2014', 'Dec-2014', --- 'Dec-2015', 'Jan-2016']`

then create a new table that with subject

```
# original_df = your original table
# subject = subject entered by the user
# month_list = month list created based on the values entered by the user.

# Create the dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': month_list, 'Course': [subject]* len(month_list)}, index=np.arange(len(original_df) + 1, len(month_list) + len(original_df) + 1))

# Concatenate the two dataframes
original_df = pd.concat([original_df, df])
```