# Return Pandas dataframe as JSONP response in Python Flask

Tags: python, json, pandas, flask, jsonp

I want to return data as `JSONP`response in `Flask`.

The data comes from a `Pandas dataframe` and I can return it as `JSON` with the following line:

```
json_data = dataframe.to_json(orient='values')
return json_data
```

Works fine and I get the data, which looks like this:

> [[1487310600000,1038,1042,1038,1038,-2.243,6.8933],[1487310900000,1042,1042,1038,1038,-1.3626,4.3058],[1487311200000,1042,1042,1038,1038,-1.4631,17.8684]]

But I need it as `JSONP`, so I use the following code:

```
from flask_jsonpify import jsonpify
json_data = dataframe.to_json(orient='values')
return jsonpify(json_data)
```

And it gives me the data, but with double quotes:

> "[[1487310600000,1038,1042,1038,1038,-2.243,6.8933],[1487310900000,1042,1042,1038,1038,-1.3626,4.3058],[1487311200000,1042,1042,1038,1038,-1.4631,17.8684]]"

How can I get the `JSONP` response in `Flask` without double quotes?
Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't call `to_json()` first. `jsonpify()` expects its argument to be a dictionary or list, and it converts it to JSON with the JSONP wrapper.

Comment: If I do `jsonpify(dataframe)`I get an error `is not JSON serializable`

Comment: [convert dataframe to list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112234/converting-dataframe-into-a-list)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is my solution to convert a Pandas dataframe to JSONP an return it in Flask:

```
from flask_jsonpify import jsonpify
df_list = df.values.tolist()
JSONP_data = jsonpify(df_list)
return JSONP_data
```

Depending on how you need the dataframe converted, you might need to create the list in a different way. For example like this:

```
df_list = merged.values.T.tolist()
```

Or like this:

```
df_list = list(df.values.flatten())
```

Thanks goes to the user @Barmer

Answer (score 2):

With this method, columns of dataframe will be the keys and series of dataframe will be the values.

```
data_dict = dict()
for col in dataframe.columns:
    data_dict[col] = dataframe[col].values.totlist()
return jsonify(data_dict)
```