# render data frame to a webpage

Tags: python-3.x, api

I have created a ML model and I want to publish the predictions of the test set onto a web page for better visualization for non-technical team members.

I have converted the predictions to a data frame to the case numbers of the test set and original data.

```
Predictions=pd.DataFrame({'Case.Number':CN_test,'Org_Data':y_test,'Predictions':y_pred})
```

As I am new to this, my experience with API is just of creating a basic API for hello world.

Requesting guidance on how to do this using API or any other way to get this done.

Regards

Sudhir

Comment: can anyone please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since dataframe can't be rendered directly hence it has to converted into a list 
below is the code for the same.

I got the solution in another query:

[Return Pandas dataframe as JSONP response in Python Flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42309133/return-pandas-dataframe-as-jsonp-response-in-python-flask)