# How to show values inside the bars of a bargraph?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a dataframe like this:

```
                 platform     count
release_year        
         1996    PlayStation   138
         1997    PlayStation   170
         1998    PlayStation   155
         1999    PC            243...
```

Now I want to plot horizontal bargraph with the Platform name inside the respective bars such that it looks something like this:

[image]

How do I do that?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here's the input `data.csv` file once you find the percentage in each platform:

```
Platform,Percent
Nintendo,34
PC,16
Playstation,28
Xbox,22
```

This is the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv("data.csv", index_col=0)
df.plot(kind="barh", legend=False, width=0.8)
for i, (p, pr) in enumerate(zip(df.index, df["Percent"])):
    plt.text(s=p, x=1, y=i, color="w", verticalalignment="center", size=18)
    plt.text(s=str(pr)+"%", x=pr-5, y=i, color="w",
             verticalalignment="center", horizontalalignment="left", size=18)
plt.axis("off")
# xticks & yticks have empty lists to reduce white space in plot
plt.xticks([])
plt.yticks([])
plt.tight_layout()
plt.savefig("data.png")
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if you want it to be in **Percentage %** or as **count number** itself. That's up to you to decide.
However first convert your dataframe into a list using:

```
count = df["count"].tolist()
platform = df["platform"].tolist()
```

I will not be focusing on that. You can find some help regarding that from

[Dataframe to list 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112234/converting-dataframe-into-a-list)

[Dataframe to list 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22341271/get-list-from-pandas-dataframe-column)

Once you get the below list then,

```
count = ['138','170','155','243','232']
platform =['PlayStation','PlayStation','PlayStation','PC','PlayStation']
```

*Note: The above two would be your **text labels** inside bar graphs.*

Here is the complete code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy.random import rand
from numpy import arange

count = ['138','170','155','243','232']
platform =['PlayStation','PlayStation','PlayStation','PC','PlayStation']
def autolabel(rects):
# attach some text labels
    for ii,rect in enumerate(rects):
        width = int(rect.get_width())

        height = rect.get_height()
        print(height,width)
        yloc1=rect.get_y() + height /2.0
        yloc2=rect.get_y() + height /2.0
        if (width <= 5):
            # Shift the text to the right side of the right edge
            xloc1 = width + 1
            yloc2=yloc2+0.3
            # Black against white background
            clr = 'black'
            align = 'left'
        else:
            # Shift the text to the left side of the right edge
            xloc1 = 0.98*width
            # White on blue
            clr = 'white'
            align = 'right'
        yloc1=rect.get_y() + height /2.0
        print(xloc1,yloc1,yloc2)
        ax.text(xloc1,yloc1, '%s'% (count[ii]),horizontalalignment=align,
                         verticalalignment='center',color=clr,weight='bold',
                         clip_on=True)
        ax.text(5,yloc2, '%s'% (platform[ii]),horizontalalignment='left',
                         verticalalignment='center',color=clr,weight='bold',
                         clip_on=True)


val = [138,170,155,243,232]
print(val)# the bar lengths or count in your case
pos = [ 1996 , 1997,  1998,  1999,  2000]    # the bar centers on the y axis
print(pos)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
rects = ax.barh(pos,val, align='center',height=0.4)
print(rects)
autolabel(rects)
ax.set_ylabel('Year')
ax.set_xlabel('Count')
ax.set_title('horizontal bar chart')
ax.grid(False)
plt.savefig("horizontal.png")
plt.show()
```

[image: Here is the output]

The part where you will be **interested** in very much:

```
def autolabel(rects):
    # attach some text labels
        for ii,rect in enumerate(rects):

            width =  rect.get_width()

            height = rect.get_height()

            yloc1=rect.get_y() + height /2.0
            yloc2=rect.get_y() + height /2.0
            if (width <= 5):
                # Shift the text to the right side of the right edge
                xloc1 = width + 1
                yloc2=yloc2+0.3
                # Black against white background
                clr = 'black'
                align = 'left'
            else:
                # Shift the text to the left side of the right edge
                xloc1 = 0.98*width
                # White on blue
                clr = 'white'
                align = 'right'
            yloc1=rect.get_y() + height /2.0

            ax.text(xloc1,yloc1, '%s'% (count[ii]),horizontalalignment=align,
                             verticalalignment='center',color=clr,weight='bold',
                             clip_on=True)
            ax.text(5,yloc2, '%s'% (platform[ii]),horizontalalignment='left',
                             verticalalignment='center',color=clr,weight='bold',
                             clip_on=True)
```

1) **ii** variable comes from enumerate having values 0 to 5. Used to iterate over our lists `count` and `platform`

2) Why an if/else statement in the function? That is for conditions where the width is too little. Say if the first width obtained from `val = [138,170,155,243,232]` is reduced to 5 i.e `val = [5,170,155,243,232]` in this case the output would be.

[image: This]

What we are basically doing is giving xloc (x-coordinate) and yloc (y-coordinate) values for both `ax.text()` functions.

```
ax.text(xloc1,yloc1, '%s'% (count[ii]),horizontalalignment=align,
                         verticalalignment='center',color=clr,weight='bold',
                         clip_on=True)
        ax.text(5,yloc2, '%s'% (platform[ii]),horizontalalignment='left',
                         verticalalignment='center',color=clr,weight='bold',
                         clip_on=True)
```

> **Function parameters**
>
> text(x, y, s, fontdict=None, withdash=False, **kwargs)
>
> x, y : data coordinates
>
> s : string while the other two are optional.

If width is < 5. Then increase yloc a bit. So that text is little bit higher. While change xloc acccordingly.Also changing the color to black. Or else color will be white.

It would be **best** if you change those values and see how the output changes to gain a better understanding of it.

***UPDATE:*** If you don't want the axis to be shown in the output just as in the image you attached you can simple do that typing in `ax.axis("off")`[image]